# URL Redirect web.config

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config, redirect

I have the following URL

https://www.abcsite.com/?data=w35VTqIaVXWfi4GmESj8EGCG1cdF2aT%2BUF3D?utm_source=external%20system&utm_campaign=external%20system&utm_medium=EX.com&utm_content=MMB

which has extra ? at the end. which I Would like to remove and replace with "&"

I am using following rule but it is not working. can you review this and tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="fixdata" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="\?(.*)\?(.*)$"  ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}&{R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rule should be like this:

```
<rule name="fixdata" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)\?utm_source(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}?{C:1}&amp;utm_source{C:2}" appendQueryString="False" />
</rule>
```

Your rule didnt work, because `<match url=` contains path without query string. You need to create additional condition to match query string with your regexp pattern

Comment: Thanks for this. it is working. the only issue I am facing is it also replace ? in data variable value. I just want it to replace ? before utm_source. I hope it makes sense. if you need more clarification please let me know and I will write it bit better.

Comment: Can you provide example of result URL

Comment: here is input URL"http://example/?data=a6fhD87ktNK7PxlGtDW1ge5BgE%0AK8hXp??ge%?utm_source=XX%20AXX&utm_campaign=XX%20XX&utm_medium=XX.com&utm_content=MMB" and here is output "http://example/?data=a6fhD87ktNK7PxlGtDW1ge5BgE%0AK8hXp&&ge%&utm_source=XX%20AXX&utm_campaign=XX%20XX&utm_medium=XX.com&utm_content=MMB" you will in input i have added extra ?? marks at the end of data= value. they were converted to && . I hope this helps.